# Como fazer download de arquivos do FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso fazer download de arquivos txt que estão em um FTP, tentei usar o seguinte código aprensantado abaixo para isso porem ele não faz o que preciso.

O primeiro parâmetro do método DownloadFile é a URL que eu tenho, o segundo parâmetro é obrigatório mas eu não quero definir um caminho fixo e quero que ele pegue o nome original do arquivo.

Quero que o download seja feito igual quando você baixa um arquivo como por exemplo desse site: https://jquery.com/download/ través do **Google Chrome**

Alguém por favor sabe como pode ser feito?

```
string url = "http://MeuSite/arquivo.text";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(url, "Não sei o que colocar aqui");
}
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer. Tem como dar uma explicação mais detalhada na pergunta?

Comment: se não me engano o primeiro parametro do metodo DownloadFile é a url, e o segundo é o nome do arquivo

Comment: É simples, eu tenho uma grid com uma lista de arquivos que estão no FTP para download, quando o usuário clicar em fazer download de um arquivo ele tem que baixar para a maquina do usuário. Entra nesse link do jquery e faz um download usando o navegador do Google, é exatamente isso que eu preciso. Conseguiu entender?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Eu não tinha visto a tag [tag:asp.net]. O seu único problema é o que queres pegar o nome original do arquivo para salvar no cliente, certo?

Comment: Certo, mas não quero definir um caminho fixo, quero que ele faça igual o Chrome baixando o arquivo e salvando na pasta de download do usuário logado na maquina.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz poste sua solução como resposta, depois você pode aceitá-la como solução e a pergunta não ficará sem resposta. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encontrei uma solução**

Não sei se essa solução é a mais correta mas ela faz o que eu precisava:

```
string strCaminho = "http://MeuSite/MeuArquivo.txt";
string nomeDoArquivo = "MeuArquivo.txt";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{    
    byte[] bytesFile = wc.DownloadData(strCaminho);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nomeDoArquivo + ";");
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytesFile, 0, bytesFile.Length);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é a forma mais bonita, mas você já tem o nome do arquivo na tua url, então você pode dar um split na url e pegar o nome do arquivo. Lembrando que no segundo parâmetro você define também o local que será salvo.

```
string url = "http://MeuSite/arquivo.text";
var arrayUrl = url.Split('/');            

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(url,  @"c:\ " + arrayUrl.Last());
}
```

Comment: Só pra fins de curiosidade mesmo, esse trecho `arrayUrl[arrayUrl.Length - 1]` pode ser substituído por `arrayUrl.Last()` (utilizando Linq).

Comment: Desse jeito não vai da certo, eu não quero definir tipo o caminho c:, eu quero que ele faça igual esse link do jquery, sempre salvando na pasta de download do usuário logado.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz basta buscar o local que deseja e alterar.

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior O método `Last()` é um método de extensão de `System.Linq`, portanto você precisa importar este namespace para usar a função `Last()`. O meu comentário foi uma afirmação e não uma pergunta :p

Comment: Se não passar nenhum caminho, ele nem compila.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Veja bem, eu quis dizer: **se você passar só um nome de arquivo, sem o C:\. Em que local ele tenta salvar?**. Não quis dizer para tirar o parâmetro.

Comment: @jbueno desconsidere o que disse então... Valeu pela dica!

Comment: @jbueno se não colocar o PATH ele salva na pasta do projeto.

Comment: Vou tentar dessa forma, sem o c:\

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior Mas é um projeto web, como ele vai `salvar na pasta do projeto`?

Comment: @jbueno Bah, verdade. Estou testando em console application. =/ De qualquer forma o caminho foi apontado, eu acho.

Comment: Agradeço ajuda de todos.